# Read from YAML File

Tags: java, yaml, chatbot

i have a yaml file to my chatbot i want read answer from yaml file 
exemple

> Person see hello
>   Chatbot see Hello person
>   how to do with code java to read answer from yaml file

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

- content of your yaml file :

  id_user:01

  name:Yohan

  public class User {

  ```
      private String idUser;
      private String age;

  public String getIdUser(){
     return idUser;
    } 

  public void setIdUser(String  idUser){
     this.idUser = idUser;
    }

  public String getAge(){
     return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age){
    this.age= age;
   }
  }
  ```

your Main :

```
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ReflectionToStringBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringStyle;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory;
public class YamlTesting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
        try {
            User user = mapper.readValue(new File("D:\\user.yaml"), User.class);
            System.out.println(ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(user,ToStringStyle.MULTI_LINE_STYLE));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I found this old thread and tried it on my own. I get the following error message: Error: Unable to initialize main class YamlTesting
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory
What am I missing?